# convergence of an ugly sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-functions

Determine the convergence of the sequence
$$a_n=\frac{2n+\cos (n^2)}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n}+\sin n}$$.

I knew that there is a short solution useing the L'hopital's rule (and it converges to 2), but the theorem is not allowed, but then I dont know how to prove it converges, somebody please help.

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $n$.

Comment: It is more and more obvious that L'Hopital's rule should be kicked out of curricula as soon and as completely as possible. The only effect of its presence is to make everybody stupid and unable to **look at** the sequences they are dealing with.

Comment: @Did I disagree a little bit. Teaching it later, say third or fourth year, should be enough. Occasionally, it's a handy tool.

Comment: I disagree a huge bit with did: l'Hospital's rule is a rather important and pretty handy rule to evaluate lots of kinds of limits, some of which are nearly impossible to evaluate by other more or less elementary methods. What must be addressed is the low level many students have in basic algebra and algebraic manipulations: fractions, common factor, binomials and trinomials, etc., but to put the blame on good'ol l'H is too harsh imo.

Comment: I find it amusing that anyone having problems with fractions would resort to differentiation. I dont know how to add fractions, lets throw in some limits, infinitary processes,...They are easier to understand... :-D

Answer (score 6):

$$a_n=\dfrac{2+\dfrac{\cos n^2}{n}}{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{\sin n}{n}}.$$

Comment: Damn! You beat me by 16 seconds. XD

Comment: @ParthThakkar Actually he had an error at first. In my mind you were first.

Comment: @GitGud, error? Where? I just replaced $\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n}$ by $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @GitGud, I don't know where the error was (no 'edited' link). But it doesn't matter - victory! :D

And of course, such ('unproductive') comments aren't entertained here, I know...but it's okay sometimes.

Comment: @njguliyev I apologize, then. Misread the answer.

Comment: Replaced some `\frac` by `\dfrac` (please revert the changes if you do not like the result).

Answer (score 3):

$$
a_n=\frac{2n+\cos (n^2)}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n}+\sin n}$$

or

$$ a_n = \frac{2+ \dfrac {\cos (n^2)} n}{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+ \dfrac{\sin n}{n}} $$

Now let $n \to \infty$